# Convert LineString to Polygon using Python

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to convert geometry from type: LineString into type:Polygon where each line of data is a list of coordinates and at the same time I am trying to add 2 miles radius for each coordinates within list as buffer and output should be polygons. Please see sample data as below:

```
{

"type": "FeatureCollection",

"name": "Sample_lines",

"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 123, "GLOBAL_ID": "8CAB8A", "IDENT": "41",  "TYPE": "N",  "Shape__Length": 0.2733 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -112.400011882673994, 41.0833390325461, 0.0 ], [ -112.56667894652, 41.300005042600802, 0.0 ] ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 124, "GLOBAL_ID": "9ACAVB", "IDENT": "45",  "TYPE": "N",  "Shape__Length": 0.1573 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -112.56667894652, 41.300005042600802, 0.0 ], [ -112.650011982188005, 41.4333400501312, 0.0 ] ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 125, "GLOBAL_ID": "5ACBFA", "IDENT": "48",  "TYPE": "N",  "Shape__Length": 0.4599 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -112.650011982188005, 41.4333400501312, 0.0 ], [ -113.100012081374004, 41.5000060205737, 0.0 ] ] } }

]

}
```

This is what I have tried so far and it is throwing an error as follows:

```
buffer = gpd.points_from_xy([(x,y)])
TypeError: points_from_xy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

.

Please see below code what I attempted to do:

```py
import json
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

# Load geojson 
with open('Sample_lines.geojson') as f:
    gj = json.load(f)

features = []
for f in gj['features']:

    coords = f['geometry']['coordinates']
    print(coords[0][0])
    print(coords[0][1])
    print(tuple(coords[0]))
    print(coords)
    #quit()
    # Buffer points along line
    buffers = []
    for x,y,z in tuple(coords):
        buffer = gpd.points_from_xy([(x,y)])
        buffer = buffer.to_crs(epsg=4326)
        buffer = buffer.buffer(2)
        buffers.append(buffer)
        
    # Create multipolygon from buffers    
    mpolygon = MultiPolygon(buffers)
    
    # Create feature
    features.append(
        {'geometry': gpd.GeoSeries(mpolygon).__geo_interface__,
         'properties': f['properties']}
    )

# Output new GeoJSON    
new_gj = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": features
}

# output in .GeoJSON

with open('lines2Polygon.geojson','w') as f:
    dump(new_gj, f)

print(new_gj)
```

Where am I going wrong here? Thank you in Advance for your time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors:

- the coordinate arrays should not be casted to tuple, they are ready to be looped over already
- you should pass the crs the points are in in points_from_xy
- to be able to do operations like buffers, your data should be in a projected crs. The lines you are working with are in the USA, so I chose a CRS that according to google is used a lot in the USA: EPSG:2163.
- distances should be in metric system (meter), so 1 mile is 2 * 1609.34 meter

The multipolygon created could be invalid if the individual buffers would overlap. If you use shapely.union_all on the individual buffers you can avoid overlaps. I included it like that in the script below.

The following script runs:

```
from pathlib import Path
import json
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shapely
from shapely import plotting

# Load geojson
with open(Path(__file__).with_suffix(".geojson")) as f:
    gj = json.load(f)

features = []
for f in gj["features"]:
    coords = f["geometry"]["coordinates"]
    print(coords[0][0])
    print(coords[0][1])
    print(tuple(coords[0]))
    print(coords)
    # quit()
    # Buffer points along line
    buffers = []
    for x, y, z in coords:
        buffer = gpd.points_from_xy([x], [y], crs=4326)
        buffer = buffer.to_crs(epsg=2163)
        buffer = buffer.buffer(2*1609.34)
        buffers.append(buffer)

    # Create multipolygon from buffers
    # mpolygon = shapely.MultiPolygon(buffers)
    mpolygon = shapely.union_all(buffers)
    plotting.plot_polygon(mpolygon)

    # Create feature
    features.append(
        {
            "geometry": gpd.GeoSeries(mpolygon).__geo_interface__,
            "properties": f["properties"],
        }
    )

# Output new GeoJSON
new_gj = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}

# output in .GeoJSON
with open("lines2Polygon.geojson", "w") as f:
    json.dump(new_gj, f)

print(new_gj)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello Pieter, thank you sir for your detailed response on this. Appreciate it. I am getting an error as: "NameError: name 'shapely' is not defined". I made sure "pip install shapely" command ran and it is showing requirement is satisfied. Can you please provide any solution on why is this happening? Thank you. Sincerely, Tarak.

Comment: Also, Sir Pieter, I have received this error. 
```
if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3473: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation. 
```

Comment: I read over the fact that the buffers were meant to be 2 miles radius, so I changed the script to include that. To be able to use distances in meter/miles, you indeed need to to reproject the data, but to a projected crs.

Comment: For the "NameError: name 'shapely' is not defined", I'm not sure what the problem is. It seems you are using conda, did you activate the correct environment and install shapely in the right environment? Your original script already used shapely, so normaly you didn't need to install it (again) anyway...

Comment: Hi Pieter, Yeah, the new edited code worked well. And it printed as a plot but is there a way to plot this on leafleft.js using folium so I can export this as a web page? Thanks. Seems like straight forward but the exported geojson is not supporting when I try to map it on Folium. Thanks.

Comment: I've never used folium, so I cannot help you with that. Better create a seperate new question for it with the things you tried to use folium as it is not directly related to this question.

Comment: Pieter, Thank you for your time and support with this question. I will create a new question for folium related. Again, Thank you.